# Replace HTML Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

```
function toText()
{
    var convertHTML =$('#mainContent').html();
    var ele = $(convertHTML + " > span").each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(ele);


}
```

My aim is to replace the following content

```
    <div id="mainContent">
    test
<br>
    1234
<br>
    <span class="underline">test</span>
<br>
    <span class="underline">1234</span>
    </div>
```

And want my function to output test `<br> 1234 <br> test <br> 1234`

This is why i cant just use text() as it takes away the `<br>` aswell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were taking the html string returned from `$("#mainContent").html()` and trying to use it as part of the selector on the next line, when really the selector you need is `"#mainContent > span"`.

Try this instead:

```
function toText()
{
    $("#mainContent > span").replaceWith(function(){ return $(this).text(); });
}
```

You don't need an `.each()` loop: if you pass a function to `.replaceWith()` that function is called once for each element in your jQuery object and your return value is used as the replacement for the current element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7xKzP/

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
function toText()
{
    var ele = $("#mainContent > span").each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(ele);
}
```

You where using an entire block of html as a jQuery selector :)

Answer (score 1):

`convertHTML` from  `var convertHTML =$('#mainContent').html();` is not a jQuery object

You will have to write

```
var ele = $("#mainContent > span").each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
    });
```

Reason :

`$('#mainContent').html();` will return you the `string` not a jQuery object for `$.each` to work.

`var ele = $(convertHTML + " > span")` would mean

`var ele = $("test<br>1234<br><span class="underline">test</span><br><span class="underline">1234</span>" + " > span")`